# User access to documents, folders, and list without access to everything else on the site.

Tags: 2013, list, permissions, navigation

I know in the permissions settings I can give a user permissions to view documents, folders, and list via a link. However, I would like the users to be able to navigate to the documents, folders, and lists from the SharePoint 2013 site, without having access to everything else on the site, i.e. items in the quick launch bar, just access to the documents and list they they need.

Is there a way to do this? For some reason, I can give these users access to the site and they see everything, or I remove the site access and they have to use the link to get to the site contents they need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not straight forward way of doing this

1. Create a new page and use JavaScript to hide unwanted elements
2. Edit page and add your required web parts - Document Library
3. Break Permission Inheritance on that page and provide uniquer permission to the users in question